# Looping using XSLT and update a node

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML is:

```
<GrandParent>
<Parent>
    <Child1>test</Child1>
    <Child2>abc</Child2>
    <Child3>62</Child3>
    <Child4>5000061</Child4>
</Parent>
 <Parent>
        <Child1>test</Child1>
        <Child2>abc</Child2>
        <Child3>33</Child3>
        <Child4>5560853</Child4>
 </Parent>
</GrandParent>
```

and XSLT is:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="name() = 'Parent'">
    <Parent>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
             <xsl:if test = "name() = 'Child3' and /GrandParent/Parent/Child3[text() = '62']/text() and
        /GrandParent/Parent/Child4/text() = '5000061'">
        <Child3>dshgfshgfhgf</Child3>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Parent>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
 <!-- skip empty and ineligible elements -->
</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And in result instead of replacement, I am getting a new tag added as below and the if condition is getting true all the time for both :

```
<GrandParent>
<Parent>
    <Child1>test</Child1>
    <Child2>abc</Child2>
    <Child3>62</Child3>
    <Child3 >dshgfshgfhgf</Child3>
    <Child4>5000061</Child4>
</Parent>
 <Parent>
        <Child1>test</Child1>
        <Child2>abc</Child2>
        <Child3>33</Child3>
        <Child3>dshgfshgfhgf</Child3 >
        <Child4>5560853</Child4>
 </Parent>
</GrandParent>
```

I need to get the condition true for only first GrandParent tag but not the second and also Tag value should be replaced but not added.

EDIT: Correct Outcome should be like below:

```
<GrandParent>
<Parent>
    <Child1>test</Child1>
    <Child2>abc</Child2>
    <Child3> dshgfshgfhgf </Child3>
    <Child4>5000061</Child4>
</Parent>
 <Parent>
        <Child1>test</Child1>
        <Child2>abc</Child2>
        <Child3>33</Child3>
        <Child4>5560853</Child4>
 </Parent>
</GrandParent>
```

Comment: What should be the correct outcome?

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt fails because your test:

```
/GrandParent/Parent/Child3[text() = '62']
```

starts at the root node, and will be true if there is at least one `Child3` node with the value of `"62"` in the entire document. Likewise for your other test.

I would suggest you simplify your approach to:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent[Child4='5000061']/Child3[.='62']">
    <Child3>dshgfshgfhgf</Child3>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have got the out put as :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GrandParent>
   <Parent>
      <Child1>test</Child1>
      <Child2>abc</Child2>
      <Child3>62</Child3>
      <Child3>dshgfshgfhgf</Child3>
      <Child4>5000061</Child4>
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <Child1>test</Child1>
      <Child2>abc</Child2>
      <Child3>33</Child3>
      <Child4>5560853</Child4>
   </Parent>
</GrandParent>

I want the <Child3> to be replaced. not added

Comment: Well, that's easy to fix - see above.

Comment: It was not exact output which I expected. a new tag is adding instead of replacement.

Comment: You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/jxDigTM I am not able to detect any difference between the result and your expected output.

Comment: But when I am trying that in my project, I am just getting an extra tag added under <Child3>.

Comment: Did some changes. Working fine now.. Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: could you help me in adding a new node in both Parent tags?

Comment: Not in comments. I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: Posted. here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975253/add-a-new-node-in-parent-node-which-is-updated-with-text-in-xslt